# List all active multithreading.Timer objects

Tags: python, multithreading, timer

Is there a way to obtain a list of all the active [`threading.Timer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects) objects in order to [`cancel`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Timer.cancel) all of them before exiting? Otherwise the program hangs to wait their completion.

I could keep a list of them, but then I also have to remove them when they fire. Instead I wanted to know if there was a way to obtain all of them.

Comment: No, there is no automatic global list. You should register your Timers, maybe you add them to a `weakref.WeakSet`. When exiting, call `cancel()` and catch any exception.

Comment: @KlausD. seems legit, why don't you convert it to an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: They don't appear in ```threading.enumerate()``` result?

Comment: @wwii: They actually do, nice one. Add the answer so I can upvote you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`threading.enumerate()` returns a list that will include Timers that are *Alive* - they are instances of `threading._Timer`.

```
>>> t = threading.Timer(30, foo, kwargs = d)
>>> t.start()
>>> t.isAlive()
True
>>> for thing in threading.enumerate():
    if isinstance(thing, threading._Timer):
        thing.cancel()


>>> t.isAlive()
False
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to cancel the timers when exiting from the program, you can set the `daemon` flag for the timers and they will be killed on exit instead of waiting for their completion:

```
from threading import Timer
timer = Timer(10, fn)
timer.setDaemon(True)
timer.start()
```